# Passing data from tableView to another tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to send data from SportVC to CCMatchForSportTableViewController

yes I have imported the destination class in the header file in SportVC.h

```
#import "CCMatchForSportTableViewController.h"
```

this is the method to send data to second view Controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    CCMatchForSportTableViewController *matchForSport =     [[CCMatchForSportTableViewController alloc] init];
    matchForSport.sportSelected = [self.sport objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SportToMatchSegue" sender:self];
}
```

this is property in the header file in CCMatchForSportTableViewController.h

```
@interface CCMatchForSportTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *sportSelected;

@end
```

but when I do this in the viewDidLoad method in CCMatchForSportTableViewController.h and in the cell title(another method of course):

```
NSLog(@"kontolasd %@", self.sportSelected);
```

it says

```
kontolasd (null)
```

Comment: It's in `prepareForSegue:sender` that you have to put the VC and set line.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` it's going to load your view controller from your storyboard.  The one you created and used for `matchForSport.sportSelected` is going to be released when the method ends.  You need to implement a `prepareForSegue` method and make your assignment there, using the destination controller.

Answer (score 0):

When the view loads of course no rows are selected, you need to move that line inside of didselect:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                       didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    CCMatchForSportTableViewController *matchForSport =    
                                    [[CCMatchForSportTableViewController alloc] init];
    matchForSport.sportSelected = [self.sport objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.sportSelected = matchForSport.sportSelected;
    NSLog(@"kontolasd %@", self.sportSelected);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SportToMatchSegue" sender:self];
}
```

this will show you selected values, then in `performSegue` delegate method you can pass value to the next controller.